# How to pas chrome-options into selenium-requests

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to do a POST request to a jenkins server and I need to login headlessly... However, I can't seem to figure out how to pass the chrome options into selenium-request...

First, I ran this simple request to test out the options and my chrome settings and it worked perfectly...

```
# pip3 install selenium

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver

link = "https://www.google.com"
PROXY = "proxy.com:80" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
chrome.get(link)


time.sleep(3)
page = chrome.page_source
chrome.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
container = soup.find_all('div')
print(container)
```

I had perfect output, but this time, I am attempting to send a post  with authentication in a headless fashion and the error points to chrome crashing...

The new code I am working on is:

```
# pip install selenium
# pip3 install beautifulsoup4
# pip3 install wheel
# pip3 install pandas
# pip3 install selenium-requests

import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from seleniumrequests import Chrome

juser = os.environ['jen_user']
jtoken = os.environ['jen_token']
jhost = os.environ['jen_host']
jproxi = os.environ['jen_proxi']

webdriver = Chrome()
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % jproxi)
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
#chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
#chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
chrome.request('POST', jhost, data={juser:jtoken})

# Dump test data
time.sleep(3)
page = chrome.page_source
chrome.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
container = soup.find_all('div')
print(container)
```

and the error I recieved was :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    webdriver = Chrome()
  File "/home/adminx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seleniumrequests/request.py", line 144, in __init__
    super(RequestsSessionMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/adminx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/adminx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/home/adminx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 269, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/adminx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 360, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/adminx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/adminx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55d454bd7a23 <unknown>
#1 0x55d4546a2e18 <unknown>
#2 0x55d4546c61f1 <unknown>
#3 0x55d4546c191a <unknown>
#4 0x55d4546fc74a <unknown>
#5 0x55d4546f6883 <unknown>
#6 0x55d4546cc3fa <unknown>
#7 0x55d4546cd4c5 <unknown>
#8 0x55d454c0716d <unknown>
#9 0x55d454c1d5bb <unknown>
#10 0x55d454c08e75 <unknown>
#11 0x55d454c1de85 <unknown>
#12 0x55d454bfc86f <unknown>
#13 0x55d454c38ae8 <unknown>
#14 0x55d454c38c68 <unknown>
#15 0x55d454c53aad <unknown>
#16 0x7fea13be7609 <unknown>
```

The ENV:

I am testing the script with python on ubuntu 20 (WSL).
I am run this script against an normal jenkins server with not special config. (It's a the standard docker image from dockerhub.) However, I seem to have an issue with the chrome options not being picked up with selenium-requests... Has anyone encountered this before?

Thanks in advance!

E

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer is that you have to use a session. Perhaps it will save people time later on down the road.

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    site_session = s.get(jhost, verify=False)
    save_cookies(site_session.cookies, "cookies.pkl")

    page = browser.request('POST', jhost, auth=auth, verify=False, cookies=load_cookies("cookies.pkl"))
    print(page.status_code)
```